# Логирование http запросов Spring Boot

Tags: http, spring-boot, логирование

У меня есть следующий `RestController`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/reports")
public class ReportsRestController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportsRestController.class);

    ...

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/{reportId}/builder")
    ReportsLog buildReport(@PathVariable Integer reportId,
                        @RequestBody(required = false) List<ReportsParams> requestBody) {
        logger.info("Request body: " + requestBody);
        ...
    }
}
```

Как можно залогировать тело входящих запросов?

Я пыталась логировать с помощью `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`:

```
@Bean
public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter loggingFilter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    loggingFilter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
    loggingFilter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    loggingFilter.setIncludePayload(true);
    loggingFilter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
    return loggingFilter;
}
```

и это логирование вроде работает:

```
10-04-2018 12:31:00.665|[...]|DEBUG| Before request [uri=/reports/...;client=...]
10-04-2018 12:31:00.679|[...]|INFO | Request body: [ReportsParams: [name : status, defaultValue : 1, type : list ], ReportsParams: [name : tariff_polycy, defaultValue : 1, type : sql ], ReportsParams: [name : output_format, defaultValue : html, type : null ]]
10-04-2018 12:31:00.725|[...]|DEBUG| After request [uri=/reports/...;client=...;payload=[{"name":"status","defaultValue":"1","type":"list"]
```

но видно, что в payload логируется не всё тело запроса, а только начало, а окончание обрезается. Как это исправить? Или как по-другому залогировать входящие запросы?

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен что это поможет конкретно в данном случае (думаю автор вопроса уже и сам решил данный вопрос), но может кому будет полезно, для того чтобы изменить длину выводимого в payload текста нужно добавить ещё одну строчку настройки:

```
loggingFilter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
```

То есть весь код будет выглядеть так:

```
@Bean
public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter loggingFilter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    loggingFilter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
    loggingFilter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    loggingFilter.setIncludePayload(true);
    loggingFilter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
    loggingFilter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
    return loggingFilter;
}
```